# Get first row for one group

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, greatest-n-per-group

I want to get the first row for every GV(TeacherID)

```
GV |   Class|  SUM 
GV1|   L001 |  5000 
GV1|   L002 |  5000 
GV1|   L003 |  5000 
GV2|   L002 |  7000 
GV2|   L003 |  7000 
GV2|   L001 |  7000 
GV3|   L001 |  8000 
GV3|   L002 |  8000 
GV3|   L003 |  8000
```

Help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: ok, now you've edited the question such that this answer looks completely irrelevant...sigh...I'll leave it in case it helps you get started. Cheers.

---

The simplest solution given your specs:

```
  select teacherid 
    from mytable 
group by teacherid;
```

If you need other information in addition to the `teacherid`:

```
  select teacherid, ...other cols...
    from (select teacherid, ...other cols...
                 row_number() over (
                     partition by teacherid
                     order by classid /* or class as per edit */) as row_num
            from mytable) my_derived_table
   where my_derived_table.row_num = 1;
```

Caveat emptor: I don't have an installation of SQL-Server handy to test on, so syntax may not be exactly correct; but it's close.

Comment: thank you so much. But way 2 is right that I need.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH T AS (
    SELECT yourTable.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY TeacherID 
      ORDER BY ClassID) AS RN
    FROM yourTable 
)
SELECT * 
FROM T
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: It's interesting.Thanks you so much

Answer (score 1):

**DDL**

```
create table #t
(
    GV  varchar(4),
    Class varchar(4),
    [SUM] int
)
```

---

**Sample Records**

```
insert into #t(GV, Class, [SUM])values('GV1', 'L001', 5000)
insert into #t(GV, Class, [SUM])values('GV1', 'L002', 5000)
insert into #t(GV, Class, [SUM])values('GV1', 'L003', 5000)
insert into #t(GV, Class, [SUM])values('GV2', 'L002', 7000)
insert into #t(GV, Class, [SUM])values('GV2', 'L003', 7000)
insert into #t(GV, Class, [SUM])values('GV2', 'L001', 7000)
insert into #t(GV, Class, [SUM])values('GV3', 'L001', 8000)
insert into #t(GV, Class, [SUM])values('GV3', 'L002', 8000)
insert into #t(GV, Class, [SUM])values('GV3', 'L003', 8000)
```

---

**Query**

```
Select GV, class, [sum] from
(
    Select Row_Number() Over(Partition by GV Order by GV ) as RowId, * from #t
)K
Where RowId = 1

drop table #t
```

---

**Resultset**

```
GV   class sum
---- ----- ----
GV1  L001  5000
GV2  L002  7000
GV3  L001  8000
```